# Does a Framework exist for building a virtual super (acting as single) computer?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, virtualization

There are clustering or grid computers today, still it's not transparent for application developers: they cannot develop as if it was a single computer, doesn't such a framework exist today ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes.](http://www.mosix.org/txt_about.html)

Comment: Great ... if you have also for Windows I'll take :)